# allow one entry based on email address

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that successfully captures data, but I want to limit the  the amount of entries by a user based on their email address.  I am using SQL Server and VB.NET and would like to be able to check against the database, and if your email addess is in the system, popp up a message that says, "Sorry, you have already entered the system with that email address".

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that returns a boolean that takes the email address you want to check as an input parameter.  Return the correct boolean value based on the existence of the passed email address.

```
Private Function EmailExists(ByVal emailAddress As String) As Boolean
    ' TODO: Implement check against existing addresses.
    ' 1.  Declare the query you want to execute.
    ' 2.  Open a connection to the database.
    ' 3.  Execute the query.

    ' TODO: Check the result and return
    'Return true if email exists, false if it does not.
End Function
```

Use this method to check if an address exists to conditionally allow the entry to be entered.

Comment: shaun, can you elaborate the TODO and return if it exists?...this is my first time checking against DB for existing data...still learning.

Comment: It's tough for me to write the function for you considering I don't know your schema.  I did edit to give a bit more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method that returns a boolean and takes in an email address, have this method return true if the email address is found in the Database (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Email = "passed in email").

Call this method when the form is submitted and display a message box if it returns true.

Comment: sorry...I am unclear on how to write a method that returns a boolean.  Do you have example code?

Comment: The other answer has given you an outline, writing the SQL query should be fairly simple.